# Exception in Install4j when creating an 32 bit Installer with bundled JRE

Tags: install4j

Using Apache ANT I create a JRE bundle of a 32 bit JRE 1.8.202 using createbundle.exe:

```
<property name="CREATEBUNDLE" value="${install4j.path}/bin/createbundle.exe" />

<exec executable="${CREATEBUNDLE}">
<arg value="-o" />
<arg value="${install4jJREBundleDir}/${CURRENT_JRE_NAME}/" />
<!-- input -->
<arg value="${unzippedJREDirectory}/${JREDirName}/" />
</exec>

<!-- Get filename of created JRE Bundle -->
<fileset id="contents" dir="${install4jJREBundleDir}/${CURRENT_JRE_NAME}/" includes="*.tar.gz" />

<pathconvert property="INSTALL4J_JREBUNDLE" refid="contents" />
```

Using this bundle I try to create a 32 bit installer for my application:

```
<target name="installer.internal">
<install4j projectfile="${i4jprojectfile}" verbose="true" mediatypes="${i4jmediatypes}" destination="${dist}" >
<vmParameter value="-Dinstall4j.timestampUrl=${INSTALL4J_TIMESTAMP_URL}"/>
<variable name="BUILD_VERSION" value="${BUILD_VERSION}" />
<variable name="SOFTWARE_VERSION" value="${SOFTWARE_VERSION}" />
<variable name="PLATFORM_DETAIL_STRING" value="${PLATFORM_DETAIL_STRING}" />
<variable name="INSTALL4J_JREBUNDLE" value="${INSTALL4J_JREBUNDLE}" />
</install4j>
</target>
```

The following error is thrown when creating the installer:

```
350 [install4j] com.exe4j.a.d: Cannot bundle a 64-bit JRE with a 32-bit media file.
351 [install4j] at com.install4j.b.g.g.a(ejt:97)
352 [install4j] at com.install4j.b.b.a(ejt:175)
353 [install4j] at com.install4j.b.i$a.c(ejt:846)
354 [install4j] at com.install4j.b.i$a.b(ejt:837)
355 [install4j] at com.install4j.b.i.b(ejt:163)
356 [install4j] at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.c(ejt:479)
357 [install4j] at com.exe4j.a.a(ejt:342)
358 [install4j] at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.main(ejt:94)
359 [install4j] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
360 [install4j] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
361 [install4j] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
362 [install4j] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
363 [install4j] at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)
364 [install4j] at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
365 [install4j] at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
    366 [install4j] install4j: compilation failed. Reason: Cannot bundle a 64-bit JRE with a 32-bit media file.
```

The JRE in the bundle is 32 bit, so the error doesn't really make sense.

Edit: I tried using install4j v7.0.18 and Install4j8.

Comment: What is the name of the JRE bundle file?

Comment: createbundle.exe -o c:\jres\jre-8u202-windows-i586 c:\temp\tmp_jre_package-cbuild\jre1.8.0_202 The bundle file created is called windows-x86-1.8.0_202.tar.gz

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually using that bundle file? This message is only displayed if the file name contains "x64", "amd64", "arm64" or "aarch64".

Comment: We set the "INSTALL4J_JREBUNDLE" property to the windows-x86-1.8.0_202.tar.gz bundle path. So yes, I think we are using that bundle. So install4j just parses the bundle file name to check for 64- or 32 bit JRE?

Comment: INSTALL4J_JREBUNDLE must be one of your variables, do you use that in the manual configuration on the "Bundled JRE" step of the media wizard? Try adding the path explicitly. And yes, the architecture is determined from the file name.

Comment: I think I solved it. The architecture is determined from the absolute path of the bundle file. Our bundle file resides in a folder called 'c:\src\Windows10_x64\...' Because of the 'x64' in the path install4j thought the bundle is 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The architecture is determined from the absolute path of the bundle file. Our bundle file resides in a folder called 'c:\src\Windows10_x64...' Because of the 'x64' in the path ('Windows10_x64') Install4j thought the bundle is 64 bit.

Edit: The solution was to use a relative path for the bundle file omitting the 'Windows10_x64' folder.

Comment: Thank you, we will fix this for the next bugfix release